Polynomial plot looks a bit ugly
Here is my code for a degree 2 regression:
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
model =LinearRegression()
data =pd.read_csv("Regression.csv")

data['X^2'] =data['X']**2
print(data.head())
y =data['Y'].values
X =data.drop('Y',axis=1).values
print(X)
model.fit(X,y)
print(model.score(X,y))
predicted =model.predict(X)
plt.scatter(data['X'],data['Y'])
plt.plot(X[:,0],predicted)
plt.show()

The score is pretty good : 0.9999827518179073, but when I run  plot  X versus Y, my chart looks like very ugly, here is diagram:

I was expecting a nice chart like it would be done in Excel. How can I improve the regression visualization?
Here is the corresponding Excel regression chart:

Based on  recommendations, I have done it like this:
data = data.sort_values("X")

and the result is this:

but please explain to me why this works?

You need to sort by the x-axis column before you split/fit the data, otherwise the lines zigzag out of order like your top plot. Use something like data = data.sort_values("NAME_OF_X_AXIS_COLUMN") before the data.head() line.

@tdy could you explain me  please why does it  work?

Because matplotlib just does "connect the dots" in point order.  If the first point is X=22 and the next has x=34 and the next has x=24, then it's going to draw lines all over the graph.  You are EXPECTING the lines to be drawn in X order, but you didn't ask for that.

@AIML hey, post your answer to the question and accept it, don't edit it inside the question. By doing so, others can find the answer to a similar question to yours more easily

This is happening because your data isn't sorted.  Matplotlib plots the points in the order it receives them, but as the data isn't ordered on the X column, it is essentially plotting points at random and drawing a line between each random point, hence the zig zags on your original plot.
You can solve this by ordering your data by the 'X' column before using it, by using pandas.sort_values() like this: data = data.sort_values("X")
full code:
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

model = LinearRegression()
data = pd.read_csv("Regression.csv")
data = data.sort_values("X")
data['X^2'] = data['X']**2
print(data.head())

y = data['Y'].values
X = data.drop('Y',axis=1).values
print(X)

model.fit(X,y)
print(model.score(X,y))

predicted = model.predict(X)
plt.scatter(data['X'], data['Y'])
plt.plot(X[:,0], predicted)
plt.show()

Note: You can also get a dashed line for your model fit by adding '--' to plt.plot() like this:
plt.plot(X[:,0], predicted, '--')

